# У кого-то есть что-то... Где сказуемое?

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

*У Маши есть кошка.* Каким членом предложения является "кошка"?

Comment: По здешней традиции, для получения ответа на _учебный_ вопрос вам нужно сначала предложить _свой_ вариант ответа.

Comment: @Alex_ander в данном случае я бы не ставил вопрос ребром. Это частый вопрос для изучающих основы синтаксиса. Хотя, может, автор и попытается сам ответить...

Answer (score 1):

*У Маши есть кошка.*

(Кто?) кошка — подлежащее.
(Что о ней говорится?) есть — сказуемое со значением бытия.
(У кого?) у Маши — дополнение.

Comment: Ни запятых, ни тире, а где и просто слиплось... (У кого?) у Людмилы.

Comment: @shampar (Кто?) я (что сделал?) "разлепил". Теперь стало лучше?

Comment: Девицей был бы краше. В том смысле, что девушка должна была сама.